# How priority queue is used with heap to solve min distance

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, priority-queue, dijkstra

Please bear with me I am very new to data structures.

I am getting confused how a priroity queue is used to solve min distance. For example if I have a matrix and want to find the min distance from the source to the destination, I know that I would perform Dijkstra algorithm in which with a queue I can easily find the distance between source and all elements in the matrix.

However, I am confused how a heap + priority queue is used here. For example say that I start at `(1,1)` on a grid and want to find the min distance to `(3,3)` I know how to implement the algorithm in the sense of finding the neighbours and checking the distances and marking as visited. But I have read about priority queues and min heaps and want to implement that.

Right now, my only understanding is a priority queue has a key to position elements. My issue is when I insert the first neighbours `(1,0),(0,0),(2,1),(1,2)` they are inserted in the pq based on a key (which would be distance in this case). So then the next search would be the element in the matrix with the shortest distance. But with the pq, how can a heap be used here with more then 2 neighbours? For example the children of `(1,1)` are the 4 neighbours stated above. This would go against the `2*i` and `2*i + 1` and `i/2`

In conclusion, I don't understand how a min heap + priority queue works with finding the min of something like distance.

```
    0 1 2 3
     _ _ _ _
0 - |2|1|3|2|
1 - |1|3|5|1|
2 - |5|2|1|4|
3 - |2|4|2|1|
```

Comment: To confirm that I've understood the problem you're trying to solve: you have a grid, and you want to find the shortest path from one location to another. Are the grid cells each assigned numbers indicating the cost of moving there? Or is it a simpler "there's a wall here" / "there's no wall here?"

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes they are numbered I will update it. Yes there are boundaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the priority queue to get the minimum weights in every move so the MinPQ will be fit for this.

MinPQ uses internally technique of heap to put the elements in the right position operations such as `sink()` `swim()`

So the MinPQ is the data structure that uses heap technique internally

Comment: So for example the pq would be of length 1 (source). Then when I add the 4 neighbours they will use swim to position them correctly in the queue? I think my misunderstanding is what is the root node? Is this always the source node?

Comment: The root node will be the minimum value in the tree

Comment: So instead of doing a ```pq.add(node)``` its better to use ```swim()``` after the add?

Comment: Use `pq.add(node)` from outside MinPQ and internally will use `swim()`

Comment: The minimum value is what though? The distance from the source accumlative?

Comment: Yes you are right, So it's Shortest path based on weights

Comment: so when I add the node into the pq, I need to do a ```swim()``` on the new added node right? What do you mean by internally?

Comment: I mean the user who uses MinPQ will use `add(int) or `insert(int)` but he/she doesn't know how the MinPQ actual works, kind of `Data abstraction`

Comment: Yes after any insertion you need to  `swim()` to adjust the MinPQ with the right position

Comment: Okay, so correct me if I am wrong. How does one check all neighbours if we cannot remove elements from the pq? For example Is it better to use a queue (not pq) to find all distances from source and add to a priority queue since the pq cannot be empty? I.e. remove head of queue, add neighbours, remove head of queue check neighbours... etc.

Comment: Yes, you can but how much this operation will take?  the MinPQ efficient for this task. because it will take `O(1)` to query about the min

Comment: but how does a priroty queue representing a minheap find all neighbours. pq.getmin() will always be the source so how does it find all other neighbours without removing elements from the priorityqueue heap?

Comment: And for `deleteMin()`  operation will take `O(lgN)`

Comment: why are we deleting the min that is what I dont get?

Comment: Some implementations of `MinPQ` has `getMin()` return the min in the MinPQ and `deleteMin()` to return the min and delete from the MinPQ

Comment: So the logic hear to use kind of data structure efficient for finding the min value if you use normal search  will take kind of  `O(n)`

Comment: The MinPQ is efficient to get the min values from the given input in order of `O(n)`, which we need to perform Dijkstra

Comment: I'm lost. Why do we want to delete the min value from the pq? I need that there to order the queue correctly. Once the min value is gone I cant get that back?

Comment: we need this vertex to get its adjacencies and from one of the adjacencies, we go forward

Comment: I understand that, But then the heap will be empty eventually? How would i get the values of distanceS? I would need another array to store the accumilative distances?

Comment: Yes you need that

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're getting stuck at this point:

> But with the pq, how can a heap be used here with more then 2 neighbours? For example the children of (1,1) are the 4 neighbours stated above. This would go against the 2*i and 2*i + 1 and i/2

It sounds like what's tripping you up is that there are two separate concepts here that you may be combining together. First, there's the notion of "two places in a grid might be next to one another." In that world, you have (up to) four neighbors for each location. Next, there's the shape of the binary heap, in which each node has two children whose locations are given by certain arithmetic computations on array indices. Those are completely independent of one another - the binary heap has no idea that the items its storing come from a grid, and the grid has no idea that there's an array where each node has two children stored at particular positions.

For example, suppose you want to store locations (0, 0), (2, 0), (-2, 0) and (0, 2) in a binary heap, and that the weights of those locations are 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively. Then the shape of the binary heap might look like this:

```
               (0, 0)
              Weight 1
             /        \
          (2, 0)      (0, 2)
         Weight 2    Weight 4
           /
        (0, -2)
       Weight 3
```

This tree still gives each node two children; those children just don't necessarily map back to the relative positions of nodes in the grid.

More generally, treat the priority queue as a black box. Imagine that it's just a magic device that says "you can give me some new thing to store" and "I can give you the cheapest thing you've given be so far" and that's it. The fact that, internally, it coincidentally happens to be implemented as a binary heap is essentially irrelevant.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am looking for accumlative though. So if the root node is 1, then to position ```(2,0``` would be 3 and to ```(0,2)``` would be 5. But can you explain why ```(0,-2)``` is where it is? It should be the right child of root since its distance  4 which is less then 5.

Comment: In the example I was working through, the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4 were the accumulated weights. Remember that the shape of the binary heap has the data organized purely to keep low-weight items on the top and heavier items lower, and the parent-child relations there have absolutely nothing to do with the positions of the items in the grid.